# Redirect subdomain to an external secured URL

Tags: ssl, https, certificate

I have a domain name (www.domain.com) and subdomains that are only used to redirect users to the correct application.

For ex, todo.domain.com redirects to the proper TODO website's URL.

The problem is I want to make the redirection invisible to the user, ie the URL in the browser must show todo.domain.com instead of the external URL but it doesn't work if the external URL is secured, ie has a HTTPS protocol.

It works when the redirection is visible, but when I change it to invisible, the browser says "URL doesn't allow connection".

How can I do this please ?

Note: the domain name is hosted at a hosting company, we don't host it ourselves

Comment: So the provider of the website told us to add a DNS redirection (CNAME) and the invisible redirection works.

But we get a message saying the connection is not secured and we shouldn't go there. If we click on More parameters and then Proceed to the website, it's all good, however we would like to save that step.

Answer (score 0):

The server that hosts the website sends a TLS certificate when connecting on HTTPS. The TLS certificate has to list all of the domains that you connect to it with. You can see what domains are included in the certificate by clicking the padlock near the address bar and viewing the certificate.

Comment: Same question :) Does that mean that the our application provider has to add our sub-domain URL to his certifcate ? They ask that we buy a Comodo certificate that we install on our server and send them

Answer (score 0):

This is because the redirection is not being explicit about HTTP vs HTTPS,

So if I go to to a CNAME test.mydomain.com my browser will stay showing test.mydomain.com 
even though I'm connecting to www.mydomain.com invisibly.

The problem with this is that the receiving server has to identify it is serving test.mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com because the browser is expecting an SSL Response from the hostname it's connecting to if the browser thinks it's connecting to test.mydomain.com and then gets an SSL Certificate for www.mydomain.com the browser is going to go "Oh Hell no, that certificate does not match, So warning the user about this"

When using CNAMES you must always have an SSL certificate that covers all domains allowed to connect to that website

Comment: Does that mean that the our application provider has to add our sub-domain URL to his certifcate ? They ask that we buy a Comodo certificate that we install on our server and send them

Comment: Ok for starters don't by a Comodo Certificate use Let's Encrypt to get a certificate, and no they don't have to add you to there certificate they could set up a Virtual Host that uses a different certificate via SAN (Subject Alternative Names) this allows you to have multiple SSL's on the same IP Address.

So they can use Let's Encrypt instead of you getting an SSL Signed for there server and set up a Virtual Host with your TDL and use Lets Encrypt to verify that the domain does point at there server and if it does it will create a certificate

Comment: ok thanks, I'll check that with the provider. But they asked that we get a certificate and send them so I'm not sure whether they'll agree to your solution. Do you see any reason why they would only accept the certificate option ?